# nodejs / lodash include external functions as if local

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have some functions in another file that i need to include in one of my core files. I don't want to require them or `_.extend` them as I don't want to use the var name every time i need to call those.

I need to use them directly as if they're in the root scope of my core file.

I just need to keep them separated for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can require single functions/values from a module instead of requiring the whole module. So if you have:

bar.js:

```
module.exports = {
    incrementer: function(x) { return x+1 }
}
```

you can do this:

```
var foo = require('./bar.js).incrementer`
foo(5) // 6
```

instead of this:

```
var barModule = require('./bar.js)`
barModule.incrementer(5) // 6
```

If you need to import multiple members from the same external module and use ES6 there exists an easier shorthand syntax for the import part:

`import {incrementer, decrementer} from './bar.js'` instead of multiple `require` rows.